# Python - ImportError: Could not find 'nvcuda.dll'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow, object-recognition

i just want to make object recognition from inception pre trained model using tensorflow & i am using this code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import os.path
import re
import sys
import tarfile

import numpy as np
from six.moves import urllib
import tensorflow as tf

FLAGS = None

# pylint: disable=line-too-long
DATA_URL = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/image/imagenet/inception-2015-12-05.tgz'
# pylint: enable=line-too-long


class NodeLookup(object):

  def __init__(self,
               label_lookup_path=None,
               uid_lookup_path=None):
    if not label_lookup_path:
      label_lookup_path = os.path.join(
          FLAGS.model_dir, 'imagenet_2012_challenge_label_map_proto.pbtxt')
    if not uid_lookup_path:
      uid_lookup_path = os.path.join(
          FLAGS.model_dir, 'imagenet_synset_to_human_label_map.txt')
    self.node_lookup = self.load(label_lookup_path, uid_lookup_path)

  def load(self, label_lookup_path, uid_lookup_path):
    if not tf.gfile.Exists(uid_lookup_path):
      tf.logging.fatal('File does not exist %s', uid_lookup_path)
    if not tf.gfile.Exists(label_lookup_path):
      tf.logging.fatal('File does not exist %s', label_lookup_path)

    # Loads mapping from string UID to human-readable string
    proto_as_ascii_lines = tf.gfile.GFile(uid_lookup_path).readlines()
    uid_to_human = {}
    p = re.compile(r'[n\d]*[ \S,]*')
    for line in proto_as_ascii_lines:
      parsed_items = p.findall(line)
      uid = parsed_items[0]
      human_string = parsed_items[2]
      uid_to_human[uid] = human_string

    # Loads mapping from string UID to integer node ID.
    node_id_to_uid = {}
    proto_as_ascii = tf.gfile.GFile(label_lookup_path).readlines()
    for line in proto_as_ascii:
      if line.startswith('  target_class:'):
        target_class = int(line.split(': ')[1])
      if line.startswith('  target_class_string:'):
        target_class_string = line.split(': ')[1]
        node_id_to_uid[target_class] = target_class_string[1:-2]

    # Loads the final mapping of integer node ID to human-readable string
    node_id_to_name = {}
    for key, val in node_id_to_uid.items():
      if val not in uid_to_human:
        tf.logging.fatal('Failed to locate: %s', val)
      name = uid_to_human[val]
      node_id_to_name[key] = name

    return node_id_to_name

  def id_to_string(self, node_id):
    if node_id not in self.node_lookup:
      return ''
    return self.node_lookup[node_id]


def create_graph():
  # Creates graph from saved graph_def.pb.
  with tf.gfile.FastGFile(os.path.join(
      FLAGS.model_dir, 'classify_image_graph_def.pb'), 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')


def run_inference_on_image(image):
  if not tf.gfile.Exists(image):
    tf.logging.fatal('File does not exist %s', image)
  image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image, 'rb').read()

  # Creates graph from saved GraphDef.
  create_graph()

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('softmax:0')
    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor,
                           {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
    predictions = np.squeeze(predictions)

    # Creates node ID --> English string lookup.
    node_lookup = NodeLookup()

    top_k = predictions.argsort()[-FLAGS.num_top_predictions:][::-1]
    for node_id in top_k:
      human_string = node_lookup.id_to_string(node_id)
      score = predictions[node_id]
      print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))


def maybe_download_and_extract():
  """Download and extract model tar file."""
  dest_directory = FLAGS.model_dir
  if not os.path.exists(dest_directory):
    os.makedirs(dest_directory)
  filename = DATA_URL.split('/')[-1]
  filepath = os.path.join(dest_directory, filename)
  if not os.path.exists(filepath):
    def _progress(count, block_size, total_size):
      sys.stdout.write('\r>> Downloading %s %.1f%%' % (
          filename, float(count * block_size) / float(total_size) * 100.0))
      sys.stdout.flush()
    filepath, _ = urllib.request.urlretrieve(DATA_URL, filepath, _progress)
    print()
    statinfo = os.stat(filepath)
    print('Successfully downloaded', filename, statinfo.st_size, 'bytes.')
  tarfile.open(filepath, 'r:gz').extractall(dest_directory)


def main(_):
  maybe_download_and_extract()
  image = (FLAGS.image_file if FLAGS.image_file else
           os.path.join(FLAGS.model_dir, 'cropped_panda.jpg'))
  run_inference_on_image(image)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument(
      '--model_dir',
      type=str,
      default='/tmp/imagenet',
      help="""\
      Path to classify_image_graph_def.pb,
      imagenet_synset_to_human_label_map.txt, and
      imagenet_2012_challenge_label_map_proto.pbtxt.\
      """
  )
  parser.add_argument(
      '--image_file',
      type=str,
      default='',
      help='Absolute path to image file.'
  )
  parser.add_argument(
      '--num_top_predictions',
      type=int,
      default=5,
      help='Display this many predictions.'
  )
  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

i find this code from this [repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/imagenet/classify_image.py) when i simple run this by giving command in cmd "python classify.py" then it show me this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users---\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 62, in preload_check
>       ctypes.WinDLL(build_info.nvcuda_dll_name)
>     File "C:\Users---\Python\Python36\lib\ctypes__init__.py", line 348, in **init**
>       self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
>   OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "obj_recog.py", line 41, in
>   
>       import tensorflow as tf   File "C:\Users---\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py",
>   line 22, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import   File
>   "C:\Users---\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py",
>   line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "C:\Users---\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 30, in 
>       self_check.preload_check()   File "C:\Users---\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py",
>   line 70, in preload_check
>       % build_info.nvcuda_dll_name) ImportError: Could not find 'nvcuda.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a
>   directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Typically
>   it is installed in 'C:\Windows\System32'. If it is not present, ensure
>   that you have a CUDA-capable GPU with the correct driver installed.

Comment: What GPU do you have, are the drivers up to date? I'd guess it uses something like this: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads. You'll need an Nvidia GPU.

Comment: Could not find 'nvcuda.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Typically it is installed in 'C:\Windows\System32'. If it is not present, ensure that you have a CUDA-capable GPU with the correct driver installed . This line can guide you through, are you sure you have it installed? is it in the PATH?